# Cloudflare - No further requests possible during download

Tags: node.js, express, reverse-proxy, cloudflare

My site allows users to download big .zip files. A problem I'm dealing with right now is that whenever the user is currently downloading such a file, **all** other requests to the site wait until the download is finished or cancelled, making the site practically unusable. In the Chrome network tab, the request shows as pending. Why could this be?

The server itself is implemented in Node.js using Express and is proxied through NGINX and then through Cloudflare. When I connect to the Express server or the NGINX proxy directly, this problem doesn't come up, only when it's routed through Cloudflare from what I have observed.

This is my NGINX config, if of any help:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name marbleland.vani.ga;
    client_max_body_size 20m;

    location / {
        proxy_pass "http://localhost:20020/";
    }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you tried from separate browsers or from separate computers?  The browser has it's own end point protection that causes it to sometimes queue up repeat requests to the same origin waiting for one to finish before starting again.  If you're trying to do load testing all from one browser on one computer, you may be misled about what the server is really capable of because of the browser's own queuing of requests.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay, update, I've tried hitting NGINX directly without Cloudflare and it worked. Seemly like this is a Cloudflare problem. Any ideas?